# Cant connect to my tigervnc server hosted on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, tcp, vnc, ufw, tigervnc

Did some basic debugging.

1. VNC session is created

vncserver -list

```
TigerVNC server sessions:
X DISPLAY # RFB PORT #  PROCESS ID
:1      5901        4479
```

2. Port 5901 is enabled in firewall

> sudo ufw allow 5901/tcp
> Skipping adding existing rule Skipping adding
> existing rule (v6)

3. NAT port is added in my router
   [image: NAT PORT]

4. netstat -tlnp
   (Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
   will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
   Active Internet connections (only servers)
   Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5901          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18830/Xtigervnc
   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
   tcp6       0      0 ::1:5901                :::*                    LISTEN      18830/Xtigervnc
   tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
   tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
   tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -

When I try to connect to the vncserver from vncconnect using 192.168.0.112:5901, its showing timed out for a response from the computer.

What else do I need to check. Am I missing out something?

Comment: `127.0.0.1:5901` looks like it is only listening on the loopback (localhost) address - in that configuration, you will need to set up an SSH tunnel in order to connect to it I think (you appear to have an SSH service listening on `0.0.0.0:22`)

Comment: Yes @steeldriver i have an active ssh connection.

Comment: Hey `vncserver -localhost no` solved the issue. Thanks :)

Comment: I'd recommend not doing that if your vncserver is exposed to the public network (which it likely is now since you set up port forwarding on the router) - VNC authentication is notoriously weak